# adding new column after union all

Tags: sql

Say I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(colA TEXT, colB TEXT, colC TEXT);

INSERT INTO table1(colA, colB, colC) VALUES ("A1", "B1", "C1");
INSERT INTO table1(colA, colB, colC) VALUES ("A2", "B2", "C2");

CREATE TABLE table2(colD TEXT, colE TEXT, colF TEXT);

INSERT INTO table2(colD, colE, colF) VALUES ("D1", "E1", "F1");
INSERT INTO table2(colD, colE, colF) VALUES ("D2", "E2", "F2");
```

And I then run the following query to append the tables together for a select few columns:

```
SELECT colA, colB FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT colD, colE FROM table2;
```

How would you add another column to the result of the union all (say colG)?
I would like to populate each row of this new column with a message 
depending on the value within colA for that row. So if the cell
content begins with an A it should say "this is an A", or if it
is a D then it should say "this is a D". Any ideas how to accomplish that? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do somethig like this:

```
Select 'This is an ' + ColA , * from (
SELECT colA, colB FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT colD, colE FROM table2) t
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various approaches.  The below shows retrieving the letter during the union.  You could just as easily retrieve the letter after the union.

MySQL doesn't support the WITH SQL-syntax, which is why I included it.  Hardly any databases don't support that, but MySQL is one of them.

[PostgreSQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f5963/15)

```
WITH union_tbl AS(
   SELECT colA, colB, left(colA,1) as letter FROM table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT colD, colE, left(colD,1) as letter FROM table2
)

SELECT colA as "colA",  -- double quotes are necessary in Pg to force case
       colB as "colB", 
       'This is a' || CASE letter WHEN 'A' THEN 'n ' ELSE ' ' END || letter as "colG"
FROM union_tbl;
```

[MySQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b78932/16)

```
SELECT colA, 
       colB, 
       concat('This is a', case letter when 'A' then 'n ' else ' ' end, letter) as colG
FROM (
   SELECT colA, colB, left(colA,1) as letter FROM table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT colD, colE, left(colD,1) as letter FROM table2
) union_tbl;
```

---

Output:

```
colA  colB  colG
A1    B1    This is an A
A2    B2    This is an A
D1    E1    This is a D
D2    E2    This is a D
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query for the desirede result in SQL.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(CAST(ColA as VARCHAR(50)),1)='A' THEN 'This is an A'
            WHEN LEFT(CAST(ColA as VARCHAR(50)),1)='D' THEN 'This is a D' 
              ELSE 'Word in ColA is not starting with A or D' --Add if required
          END ColG , * 
FROM (
       SELECT colA, colB FROM table1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT colD, colE FROM table2) t
```